# Unauthorized 401 error for permitAll() URLs

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am getting unauthorized error even for permit all URLs.

This is my security config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         
      http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> auth
            .requestMatchers("/api/public/**","/login","/register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
        

    return http.build();    
    }
    
}
```

This is my validator file:

```java
class AudienceValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {
    private final String audience;

    AudienceValidator(String audience) {
        this.audience = audience;
    }

    public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt) {
        OAuth2Error error = new OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "The required audience is missing", null);
        
        if (jwt.getAudience().contains(audience)) {
            return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
        }
        return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(error);
    }
}
```

And these are the Log files

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.0.1)[0;39m

[2m2023-02-19T22:23:00.142+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.r.apigateway.ApiGatewayApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting ApiGatewayApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 16708 (C:\PM\api-gateway - Copy\target\classes started by KrishnaGopikaUrlagan in C:\PM\api-gateway - Copy)
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:00.142+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.r.apigateway.ApiGatewayApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:00.669+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m BeanFactory id=54aac986-e0d5-38c2-b07e-9736a12b46b1
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:01.470+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:01.471+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:01.471+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'reactorDeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:01.538+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder[0;39m [2m:[0;39m No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:02.904+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5c9f1e10, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@9658b45, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@291e1f26, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1d58f1b7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2de04a13, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@738072a1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@240b8e76, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2ed115b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2c68f8e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4f68b71d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@733ad243]
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:26.660+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[     parallel-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:26.660+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[     parallel-1][0;39m [36mathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request 'GET /api/public/allergy' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:26.660+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[     parallel-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher[0;39m [2m:[0;39m No matches found
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:26.661+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[     parallel-1][0;39m [36ma.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking authorization on '/api/public/allergy' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@69b0d355
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:26.661+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[     parallel-1][0;39m [36mebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@2da15e91'
[2m2023-02-19T22:23:26.661+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[     parallel-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authorization failed: Access Denied
```

This the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway-auth0</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
      <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>netflix-candidates</id>
      <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
      <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

I tried to permit all public URLs and authenticate all the private URLs. but even though I permitted the public URLs I am getting a 401 error.  I took out the webflux dependency, added the @Configuration annotation and made some more changes based on the suggestions I got from the comments. But still, the same problem.

Please help me solve this error.

Comment: @KrishnaGopikaUrlaganti Do you want to use Webflux or Servlet? You have to use different security configurations for Webflux or Servlet. Also you have to use wildcards in your matcher, to match your called URL. And you should remove the second  `.authorizeHttpRequests()`. It makes no sense. If you get 401 your are not logged in. Check your JWT. With Spring Boot 3, you have to add `@Configuration` to your class.

Comment: There might be some more problems, we cannot see. For example: is your class in the right package?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg you were right, I added Webfluc dependency by mistake and I took that out now and also made some suggested modifications. Iam still getting the unauthorized 401 for /api/public/ urls.

Comment: could you please update your post with new logs after your modifications

Comment: The logs indicate you are still using Spring WebFlux. In your pom.xml, you are depending on `spring-boot-starter-gateway` which only works with Spring WebFlux. Therefore as @dur mentioned, your SecurityConfig is incorrect. See [Explicit WebFlux Security Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html#_explicit_webflux_security_configuration). I've updated my answer.

Comment: If my answer did in fact answer your question, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring Security 6.x, you may be missing an `@Configuration` on your `SecurityConfig`. I added a comment explaining the discrepancy between your logs and your config, so if the missing annotation is your problem, you may face further configuration issues afterwards.

See the [5.8 migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#_add_configuration_to_enable_annotations) (which should be used when upgrading to 6.0) for more info.

---

**Edit:**

Upon discussing further in comments and reviewing your updated question, it appears that you are building an application using `spring-boot-starter-gateway` (Spring Cloud Gateway), which builds on Spring WebFlux and requires a corresponding security configuration using `@EnableWebFluxSecurity`. [Explicit WebFlux Security Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html#_explicit_webflux_security_configuration) in the reference contains an example configuration to get you started with Spring WebFlux.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 6 is deny-by-default, so if you don't explicitly reference a URL, or provide a wildcard, it'll deny access. Try this:

```java
.requestMatchers("api/public/**").permitAll())
```

Comment: You might try `/api/public/**` instead.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The reference you are providing is a specific one. You need to provide a general one for spring security to either accept or reject apis that belong to that path. Try the below:
`instead of "api/public" or api/private use "api/public/*" and "api/private/*"`